# Is there an atomic way to update_option in Wordpress (to ensure data integrity)?

Tags: database, options

I want to update an option which is an array by adding a new value, but there's no atomicity or guarantee of data integrity.

**EXAMPLE**

```
//Get the option value (an array)
$val = get_option( "some-option" );

//Add to the array
$val[] = "something";

/** Here, another session might already have it and is calling "update_option" */

//Save back (this overwrites whatever that other person did)
update_option( "some-option", $val );
```

Is there anything in wordpress that offers atomicity?

Comment: You should try using the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

Comment: @ChipBennett How would that be any different? Altering an array stored in a setting would still be non-atomic. Is there a settings API call to lock a setting until unlocked? (I couldn't find it)

Comment: Essentially no, there is no locking mechanism for this in WordPress core.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the use case? What's the scenario you're attempting to cause or prevent?

Comment: @ChipBennett The use case and scenario are presented in my example. I've got an array of values (and some of those are objects or arrays as well) that can be changed and I want to ensure that it's locked whenever changes occur.

Comment: How does that happen, though? How do you envision two separate sessions attempting to modify settings? You're taking the 5-inch view of the problem. Pan out to the 5-feet view, or the 50-feet view. What's the scenario?

Comment: @ChipBennett Imagine a page that grabs info from a user. On the server side, it takes that info, gets the stored object and inserts/updates that info in the object and then saves it back to wordpress. Now imagine 100 people all doing this at the same time.

Comment: Why are front-end user data being stored as an *option*? You're describing *content*, which gets stored as *posts*.

Comment: I think @ChipBennett is on the right track. It is starting to sound like the problem is with your data design not with how options work.